# No route matches Error : ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"Show", :controller=>"teams}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

This has thrown me for a tailspin. 
I have a failing test that should be passing . I'm getting a no route error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches` from the line `get :Show, params: {id: @team}`. Everything  else in my app confirms the route `~/teams/:id` is defined, from `confing/routes.rb` to the development server.

My code:

**Failing Test**

```
test "should get show action when logged in" do
  log_in_as(@other_user)
  get :Show, params: {id: @team}
  assert_response :success
  assert_template 'teams/show'
end
```

**Error**

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"Show", :controller=>"teams", :id=>#<Team id: 1049939034, teamname: "Blue panthers" ..... >}
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
 resources :teams, only: [:show, :index]
```

**Rake Routes**

```
team GET        /teams/:id(.:format)                         teams#show
```

**Rails Console**

```
2.4.2 :011 > app.team_path(2)
 => "/teams/2"
```

**Development Server Log**

```
Started GET "/teams/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-30 21:30:51 -0400
Processing by TeamsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
  User Load (23.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Team Load (16.4ms)  SELECT  `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
  Rendering teams/show.html.erb within layouts/application
Completed 200 OK in 474ms (Views: 398.0ms | ActiveRecord: 48.6ms)
```

I'm out of ideas on how to debug this error.

Comment: Try with `get :show, params: {id: @team}`, note the difference between `Show` and `show`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, oh wow, that did the trick. Can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks.